# why is mapStateToProps returning the default/initial/empty data, when I've dispatch an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, mapstatetoprops

I've had this bug for days now, when I dispatch an action, store.getState() shows the updated state,
but when using mapStateToProps in other component, the updated state is lost, and what is shown is the default state.

[image: Console output]

On Form Submission

```js
const handleLoginSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let gottenName = name.length > 1;
    let gottenPassword = password.length > 1;

    if (gottenName && gottenPassword){
        //HERE
        props.dispatch({type:"L", payload:' name '})

    }
}



`store.getState()` Update accordingly

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

store.subscribe(()=>{
  let getName = store.getState();
  if (getName.name !== ''){
    setLoginSuccess(true);
  }
  console.log("HI",store.getState());
})
```

When I try to view the update data in other components, it only shows the default state:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("happy Birth :)",props.name);
});
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>({
   name: state
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LeftSideTop);
```

Comment: This is strange but I don’t think there’s enough information here to resolve it.  Is it possible that you have multiple store Provider components?

Comment: Where are you creating the store?  Looks almost like you are creating it inside the component which would be totally wrong.

Comment: Thank you Linda Paiste, i've done it in another way.